# Workflow migration from LN to .NET: continue active workflows where users left off?

Tags: .net, lotus-notes, workflow-foundation, sharepoint-workflow

My team is working on a project which involves migrating a legacy Lotus Notes application to .NET and SharePoint 2013.  The current application relies on a couple of native long-running workflows (some of them are active more than 2 years).

Beyond re-engineering the application and the workflows in .NET all data needs to be migrated including workflows and workflow states.  A key requirement is the ability to continue active workflows (users just pick WFs up where they left off) as well as to make completed workflows available as if they ran in the new target environment.  Maintaining both applications side by side until all active WFs finished and initiating new ones in the new application is not an option due to their average running times.

We have a hard time figuring out how to accomplish this.  We are able to export all WFs, their states and associated data to any file format.  Basically, we need a way to orchestrate the exported data in a fashion that enables the .NET Workflow Foundation to, say, "pick it up" and "continue" where users left off.  Has anyone ever faced a similar challenge and came up with a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I guess you just have to duplicate the Notes business/workflow logic exactly in .NET/Sharepoint, and it should work.
For example, if you have a status field called "WorkflowStatus" in the Notes application, with the choices "Initial", "Processing" and "Finished", you need the same options in the corresponding field in the Sharepoint application. Then it should work.

So if you want to migrate a Notes application to Sharepoint like you describe, you basically have to duplicate the functionality exactly in the new application. That is why I don't see any cost benefit in migrating off Notes, the cost to rewrite all applications with full fidelity is often substantial.
If you did not write the applications with full fidelity, you are screwed. :-)

Here is a slideshare presentation about migrations like that: 
http://www.slideshare.net/ktree19/replacing-ltus-notes-heres-how-it-really-goes-down